# Convert String To Property or Object (VBA)

Tags: string, vba, object, excel, type-conversion

I am building an array in VBA for Powerpoint.

The sub sweeps through all shapes in each slide in the presentation, and I want to store into the array:

1. The property (as string or object)
2. The value of that property.

I will then load this array into a list box.
When the user clicks on the selected item in the list box I want the property to be set with the value.

In code it would be something like this:

```
Dim s_MyProperty as string
Dim s_Value as string

'Remember the variables
s_MyProperty = ".PageSetup.SlideHeight"
s_Value = ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight

' This is the part I need help with
' Apply the property
Dim o_Object as object ' or something similar
o_Object = ActivePresentation
o_Object &  s_MyProperty = s_Value
```

The code would be similar in Excel.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check out the `CallByName` function... its an oldie but a goodie.

```
CallbyName o_Object, s_MyProperty, VbLet, s_Value
```

Comment: Happy to help :q

Thanks for the acknowledgement!